# flutter circular progress Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Am looking to implement a circular progress widget in flutter similar to the Jquery circular progress. The idea is when a button is clicked, as an activity happens in the background, the circular progress fills in color while a counter incrementally goes from 0-100%. I am able to do the circular fill using custom paint but am unable to display the actual % count as the color fills the circular progress. How would i do this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `precent_indicator` library: https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator/install

It has good features, such as showing progress around a picture:

```
  CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: 100.0,
    lineWidth: 15.0,
    progressColor: Colors.blue,
    percent: 0.4,
    center: const CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://tr.web.img4.acsta.net/c_310_420/pictures/bzp/01/61282.jpg'),
      radius: 85,
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use this plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_circular_chart
they have the component you need

Comment: I tried this but it only creates a chart. Am looking for a more progress bar kind of implementation that counts to 100 based on a running future

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iqnivek/react-circular-progressbar/HEAD/docs/animated-progressbar.gif?raw=true something like this is what am trying to implement